# What is the proper pronunciation: Tz'lafechad or Tz'lofchad?

Tags: torah-reading, pronunciation

Is the first vowel in Tz'lfchd (Bamidbar 27:1) a kamatz katan or a kamatz gadol? If it is the first, should it not be Tz'lof-chad (Ashkenazic: Tz'lof-chod) and if it is the latter, should it not be Tz'la-f'chad (Ashkenazic: Tz'lo-f'chod)?

On the Internet there is hardly any Tz'lof-chad, Tz'lof-chod, Tz'la-f'chad or Tz'lo-f'chod. Are not all other transliterations in error? Only two should be correct, no?

Comment: Kamatz Katan. Don't learn too much from internet transliteration

Comment: It's a kamatz katan, as @DoubleAA said. Interestingly enough, the Septuagint has Σαλπααδ, _Salpaad_, which eliminates the entire vowel altogether.

Comment: On the other hand, in Artscroll Jehoshua 17:3 it was transliterated in the other way. I'm puzzled, as this should be a _kamatz katan,_ and _Choglah_ is written correctly. http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0617.htm#3

Comment: Good point. ArtScroll often uses in its translation the names known in non-Jewish circles, like Gideon (gid'on) and Gershom (geireshom), as can be seen on pages 2049-2052 of their Stone Edition TeNaCh. So these are not the transliterations that they approve, I believe, but the familiar non-Jewish ones on English Bibles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already pointed out in comments, it's a *kamatz katan,* therefore it should be pronounced as *Tzelofchad* (or *Tzelofchod* in Ashkenazi). I tend to use [Dovi's online edition](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%9B%D7%96/%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D) of Tanakh, which seems to have a good quality in general, and shows *kamatz katan* with a distinct sign.

Comment: @DanF Sometimes I find it easy, like _vayamot, vayakom, vayashov,_ sometimes it's trickier. Here's a quite good French site for the rules with examples (Google Translate does an acceptable job): http://dikdouk.free.fr/VoyellesIII.htm#DeuxQamatz