# Online chumash with kometz katans indicated

Tags: product-recommendation, pentateuch-chumash

Is there a free site online that has a chumash online with kamatz katans indicated?

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91901/15256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was asked in a [similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91901/15256), and I suggested there [Dovi's online Chumash](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:Dovi/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9), which seems to be a really good quality one with the *kamatz katan* marked.

Comment: And [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:Dovi/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%95/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%91#%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%A5_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F) is the page about how they chose which kamatsim to mark